# Convert NSString to SecKeyRef to verify RSA in objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, rsa

I want to verify a data on iOS 7. Now I have a function:

```
-(BOOL) PKCSVerifyBytesSHA256withRSA:(NSData*) plainData
                            withSign:(NSData*) signature
                                withKey:(SecKeyRef) public_Key{
        size_t signedHashBytesSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(public_Key);
        const void* signedHashBytes = [signature bytes];
        size_t hashBytesSize = CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH;
        uint8_t* hashBytes = malloc(hashBytesSize);
        if (!CC_SHA256([plainData bytes], (CC_LONG)[plainData length], hashBytes)){
            return nil;
        }
        OSStatus status = SecKeyRawVerify(publicKey,
                                          kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA256,
                                          hashBytes,
                                          hashBytesSize,
                                          signedHashBytes,
                                          signedHashBytesSize);
        return status == errSecSuccess;
}
```

and a key:

```
NSString *public_key = @"MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCT2eIq8i/uAHzvwOWhFU9AuRHjPnGq8wD461ZH7N4/LjoRwPaPF3meyyENJgtDr4EyhV9KN77/3VT+87ZpT6QH9w6Q5XwDmM3jhU6bUhWyIPLzrd5XE2rQKRIMXixflz/8Q327VHKsLoKu44HuCh6XrB+uMWUjwVLCLOi2U0sYdQIDAQAB";
```

I was suggest a link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612507/nsstring-to-seckeyref)
so I add the `- (SecKeyRef)getPublicKeyRef` and `PKCSVerifyBytesSHA256withRSA` to a new class and call

```
RSA1 *rsa1 =[[RSA1 alloc]init];
    if([rsa1 PKCSVerifyBytesSHA256withRSA:Ddata withSign:Dsig withKey:[rsa1 getPublicKeyRef]]){
        NSLog(@"True");}
    else{
        NSLog(@"nil");}
```

but I got an error at the line

```
size_t signedHashBytesSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(public_Key);
```

in the `PKCSVerifyBytesSHA256withRSA` function with the note: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x10)`
Is there any way to solve this problems?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612507/nsstring-to-seckeyref)

Comment: Can you show me more clearly because I use:
if([rsa PKCSVerifyBytesSHA256withRSA:Ddata withSign:Dsig withKey:[rsa getPublicKeyRef:public_key]])
        NSLog(@"True");
    else
        NSLog(@"nil");

I got a error: 

SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef)certData);

Comment: Can you **edit** your question instead? Hard to read codes in comment.

Comment: Can you show me more clearly because I use:
`if([rsa PKCSVerifyBytesSHA256withRSA:Ddata withSign:Dsig withKey:[rsa getPublicKeyRef:public_key]]) NSLog(@"True"); else NSLog(@"nil");`
I got a error at the getPublicKey function: 
`SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef)certData);`

Comment: (facepalm) Edit the question ABOVE.

Comment: In summary, I got a error and xcode point to getPublicKeyRef function (the code in the link you suggest). 
`SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef)certData);`

Comment: what kind of error? **update** your question now. Thanks.

Comment: I already update question, Thanks @Raptor

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993505/seckeygetblocksize-or-seckeyrawverify-for-public-key-throw-exc-bad-access-code-2)

Comment: @user3659792, you should not post code snippets in a comment, it is totally unreadable – update your OP instead.

Comment: that's link not enought information for me, can you describe more clearly, @Raptor

Comment: I already update the question, @holex

Comment: @user3659792 don't wait for answer, search for more in Google. There are a couple matches. You should try to understand what you are writing.

Comment: tks for your help, @Raptor